# MySQL query - Items bought by most of the users

Tags: mysql

I am struggling here a bit.
I have two tables:
  `item(IID, description, category, price)`
  `buys(UID,IID,Price)`

The query is to find items that are bought by most of the users.
I have tried this :

```
SELECT Distinct Description, Count(buys.UID) AS TimesBought From item,buys
Where item.IId=buys.IID
Group by Description Order by TimesBought;
```

Which returns all the categories and how many times items in this category were bought.

Please help

Comment: Is the category specific to each item or can multiple items (descriptions) have the same category. Do you maybe want to show an example what you want

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here, could you clarify what's wrong with the results you're getting? (btw, the DISTINCT isn't necessary since you're GROUPing by description already)

Comment: I think you'd want to `GROUP BY category`, not description to get it to group by category.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT item.IID, Count(item.IID) AS TimesBought
From item inner join buys
on item.IId = buys.IID
Group by item.IId Order by TimesBought
```